# permission denied when creating an .html file in python

Tags: python

so this is my first python experience. I have a list of images in folder that I'm trying to convert to html pages. For that I have the following code:

```
import inspect, os, errno, markup
path =  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))+'/www/img/'
print path

for f in os.listdir(path):
  counter = 1
  page = markup.page()
  page.init(charset="UTF-8")
  from markup import oneliner as e
  page.a(e.img(src='img/'+f, width=1024, height=768), href='')
  final = open('/index'+str(counter)+'.html','w')
  final.write(page)
```

and I get an `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/index1.html'` message....
any clues or ideas are much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: You're running the script as a user without write permission to your output dir.  Only root and write to `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here: `open('/index'+str(counter)+'.html','w')`

The path starting with '/' is an absolute path, no matter what's your current directory.
And it's not a python specific.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is related to file permissions of root folder (`/`). Try running the script as root or pick some other directory that you are sure you have write access to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Unix/Linux (by the forward slashes), any path that starts with a `/` is absolute.  So you're trying to write a file named `index.html` to the root of your file system.  Only root can do that.

If you want the path to be relative, change:

```
final = open('/index'+str(counter)+'.html','w')
```

to:

```
final = open('index'+str(counter)+'.html','w')
```

Notice the missing `/` in front of `index`